# Populating a JList

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, windowbuilder

I need help populating the `JList` correctly.

When I press the >> button it should add the selected part from the left panel to the list of parts in the right panel. The << button should delete the selected part from the right panel.

I'm pretty sure I'm not using a method correctly.

```
//This Add_1 button adds the selected part from the left panel to the list of parts in the right panel.

Add_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

            DefaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();

            for(int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++)
            {
                Object item = list.getModel().getElementAt(i);

                model1.addElement(item);
                list_1.setModel(model1);
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: Button]

```
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            DefaultListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel();
            model2.addElement(list_1.getSelectedValue());
            list.setModel(model2);
        }
});
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Im pretty sure Im not using a method correctly."* You've described what you expected to happen, but not what actually happens. What actually happens? BTW - Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit to the question]().  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: Its adding all the items from the left list to the right list. I need it to add only the items I select from the left list.

Comment: Like Andrew Thompson said, we need more code. Please post only the relevant parts into your question. Also you should rename some of your variables into "talking variables". `btnNewButton_1` does not tell us what it does, `btnUpdateList` or something similar helps a lot.

Comment: @hamena314 *"only the relevant parts"* The OP often does not know what is relevant! That is why we tend to suggest posting a `[mcve]` - which **guarantees** the relevant code is included (as well as enough other code to put it on-screen - so we can also see the problem). Now the trick with those 6 chars (`[mcve]`)in a 'code comment' is that without the code comment they expand to [mcve] - an article right here on SO that goes into more detail. ..

Comment: .. @hamena314 *"Also you should rename some of your variables into "talking variables"."* But I can **fully agree** with that. I'd have used the term 'self documenting identifiers for members', but then, I did not think to mention it at all. ;) To expand: Computer code (the textual form) is made for people, not machines. Numbered fields pose no problem whatsoever for a machine, given it blindly performs the instructions of the resulting machine code, but programmers could sure use the context of meaningful identifier names to help them *understand what the code is **doing,** and **why.***